# Renaming files in Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-rename

I am working on a code to rename multiple files in a folder each month, that we currently have to do manually within my company. I am fairly new to Python, currently on lists in the Python Crash Course book.

I managed to put together the below code, but I have some questions:

```
import os
import glob

#Asks the user for the current month for renaming and for the path of the
#files
month = input("Which month's reports? Type the full name of the month: ")
path = input("Enter the file path: ")

pattern = path + "\A_BCD_012345" + "*.pdf"

result = glob.glob(pattern)

for file_name in result:
    old_name = file_name
    new_name = path + '\\' + old_name[90:99] + month + ' Report' + old_name[-4:]
    print(new_name)
```

Now, my question is how to use a wildcard to be able to be more flexible, as my current code is not great.
The files always look like the same:
A_BCD_0123456_20220901_20220930_02_V2_0000_00000_FILE_5-8 digits number which is important to keep_AB0001.pdf

I would like the files to be renamed to: 5-8 digits of important number + company name + current month Report.

Where should I search to be able to finish my code? I know I am very close, the os.rename function is still missing as I did not want to add it yet, so only the wildcards are boggling my mind yet. The important digits always come after the 10th underscore character and before the 11th one. After the 11th underscore, I would like to purge everything too to rename as I would like to.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the expected result. Maybe it is just be, but I find it hard to see what you're trying to achieve here. Is it the fact that you rely on character ranges (like ``[90:99]``) that bothers you? Or are you trying to extract something from the filename?   Also, you may want to look at pathlib. It helps to handle (without being specific to windows ``\`` or unix ``/``) directories, extensions, patterns, etc.

Comment: Hey! So, I am expecting the following result for example: 32471 October Report
I would like to extract from the original filename the numbers between the 10th and 11th underscore character. These numbers can be 5-8 digit longs and they always fall between the 10th and 11th underscore, each month. How would I go about that? What bothers me is that I am using slicing right now, but it is not good, if the folder name for the files is a different length for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your last comment make it clearer.

First of all, you need to extract that data from the file name, not from the whole path name. Otherwise if there are `_` in the dir name, you will have the same problem than with slicing.

And then, from this part, you can, for example, use split to separate from '_', and extract the part you want from it.

It could look like

```py
import pathlib

dir = pathlib.Path(path)
result = dir.glob("A_BCD_012345*.pdf")
for fullpath in result:
    filename = fullpath.stem
    num = filename.split('_')[10]
    new_name = num + month + " Report" + fullpath.suffix
    new_fullpath = dir / new_name
    # os.rename(str(fullpath), str(new_fullpath))
```

Here pathlib provides you 2 things

- Extraction of the filename, without the parent directory name. So no worry about the `_` or the number of letters that could be in it
- Extraction of the suffix. So no need for the -4 (which is ok for ".pdf")

Plus, it helps your create something more os independent. As you see, no `\` in my code. The operator `/` of pathlib concatenates a parent directory with a content name, using the needed separator for the os (so it will be a `\` on windows and a `/` for unix); and also avoid redundancy you often end up with when concatenating path strings (having a `\\`  instead of a `\`).

But, well, pathlib is not vital here. You could do without it. I just took the occasion to show it here. You can also keep your glob.glob. But you need to extract the filename (without the path) for the extraction, if you don't want, as you said, to make assumption on what is in the path (number of chars for your method, or number of _ for the new one).

You can also do that with `os.path.filename` for example.

So another version closer to yours

```py
import os
import glob

#Asks the user for the current month for renaming and for the path of the
#files
month = input("Which month's reports? Type the full name of the month: ")
path = input("Enter the file path: ")

pattern = path + "\A_BCD_012345" + "*.pdf"

result = glob.glob(pattern)

for file_name in result:
    old_name = file_name
    number = os.path.filename(file_name).split('_')[10]
    new_name = path + '\\' + number + month + ' Report' + old_name[-4:]
    print(new_name)
```

(Style note: the variable name "file_name" is not the best choice here, when it is important to make the difference between the full path, and the filename, which is the name, without the directory)

Last remark: you may also want to read about regular expressions (module `re` in python). They can be very useful to extract that kind of information. For example if you discover in the future that sometimes there are only 9 _ before the wanted part instead of 10, but with a pattern helping to see which one is the important one, a simple `split` may not cut it, when with regular expression you can do really convoluted extraction with one-liner.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your detailed explanation! I will definitely look into regex, I just found out about those today as well from my brother, but from him not in a Python setting, just in general. I will definitely try out both methods, today I rewrote my code a little bit with slicing backwards, so -18:-12 in the old file name as that also gives me the required numbers, but your code is way cleaner and it gets rid of the path, which is actually important for me, I just wasn't sure how to go about it at this point. So thank you once again!